# If you deploy an app to the cloud, what is the relation to the app source code?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

I know this is undoubtedly a very basic question, but I am having trouble getting my head around this. I was handling a handover from an app contained in Docker. The app was deployed from Docker to Azure cloud. I'm not a developer, but as the developer was leaving the company, he showed me how to re-deploy the app to Azure from Docker, if it ever needed a restart. My question is, if the Docker repo gets deleted, would the app continue to run successfully in the cloud? I am asking as it's his personal Docker account so I don't have control over that if he ever decides to delete or move the app. I think I should create a company Docker account and deploy again from there. But also as I would like to understand the process better.

My guess is that once deployed, it will run on the cloud without pulling again from Docker. Unless the app is stopped on Azure and started again, perhaps it might need to pull from Docker then?

Comment: Where is your docker images deployed?

Comment: Can you provide specifics on what the developer showed you to re-deploy the image? You seem to be talking about Docker Hub, but Azure apps generally use Azure's own container registry (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-custom-container?pivots=container-linux).

Comment: The dev used Docker Hub. And deployed the app to Azure from Docker Hub.The dev showed how to add a new web app resource on Azure and deploy from Docker Hub.

Answer (score 0):

> Unless the app is stopped on Azure and started again, perhaps it might
> need to pull from Docker then?

If the App service has been deployed and works fine. Then when it's stoped and needs to start again, doesn't need to pull the image. The image was pulled in the host when it was deployed. Only when you deploy the app service and need to redeploy again, at this time, you need to pull the image again.

Comment: If something changes in the source code on Docker Hub, if I restart the app on Azure, will it check for updates in the source code on Docker and apply these changes?

Comment: @roniac No, it won't. If you want the app to check the update when the source code is updated. You can use the continuous deployment of the Web App.

Comment: Thanks Charles. This actually wasn't my experience though. I changed something in the source code - a new key for an API authentication was provided to me - and then I committed this change to Docker Hub. After that, I restarted the web application in Azure. The API then worked correctly in the app. So I guess Azure must have pulled the new source code from Docker Hub when I clicked restart. Otherwise, the API would not have worked.